NFT , pierwsza moja kolekcja
Witam. Jestem artystą malarzem. Chciałbym stworzyć swoja kolekcję NFT. Proszę o wszelkie wskazówki i pomoc. Czy mogę stworzyć swoje NFT na waszej platformie ?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English

Check out https://truffle.wtf/creators
If you're a dev check out Metaplex suite of tools such as sugar and candy machine
